# Can I publish my paper on arxiv?

Tags: research-process, paper-submission, independent-researcher

Suppose, I introduced a new idea in mathematics, which from my perspective, may be interesting and popular in the next decades.

Given that I'm not able to publish my ideas in any prestigious journals, would it be a good idea to publish them in a public preprint server like arxiv?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Usually when a mathematician (or any academic, for that matter) is not able to publish a certain paper in a prestigious journal (e.g. it was rejected after two or three different journal attempts, or the author clearly feels the paper is not suitable for a prestigious journal), then the mathematician (or academic in general) will consider less prestigious journals, of which there are hundreds (and I'm excluding those that would be on Beall's list, which you should also exclude from consideration).

Answer (score 3):

You might be able to publish at arXiv, but that requires that you be registered there. Registration might require the endorsement of an established researcher, such as a professor. If you don't have an email address at a recognized academic institution that is likely. See https://arxiv.org/help/submit for the registration process.

People will, however, be skeptical if you suggest that you are introducing a new area of mathematics. That happens only rarely.

You can, of course, purchase your own domain and get a service provider and publish whatever you like. It will be hard to find, however.

A better plan is to try to get associated with one or more established mathematicians who can help assure others of the quality of your work, and even, perhaps, help you get published in regular venues. That requires a certain quality to the work, of course, which you will need to demonstrate to them.